# kafka couchbase sink connector getting disconnected after dumping some records

Tags: apache-kafka, couchbase, apache-kafka-connect, sink

I've installed confluent_3.3.0 and started zookeper, schema-registry and kafka broker .
And downloaded couchbase connector from below link
https://github.com/couchbase/kafka-connect-couchbase

Running sink connector using below command

```
./bin/connect-standalone etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties /home/nayangiri/couch-connect-test/kafka-connect-couchbase/config/quickstart-couchbase-sink.properties
```

After running connector, I'm starting publishing JSON using kafka-python library.

The problem is, connector is getting disconnected without dumping all published messages with below error

```
[2017-11-07 20:12:39,815] WARN This transcoder (JsonBinaryTranscoder) does not support mutation tokens - this method is a stub and needs to be implemented on custom transcoders. (com.couchbase.client.java.transcoder.AbstractTranscoder:150)
[2017-11-07 20:12:44,821] WARN This transcoder (JsonBinaryTranscoder) does not support mutation tokens - this method is a stub and needs to be implemented on custom transcoders. (com.couchbase.client.java.transcoder.AbstractTranscoder:150)
[2017-11-07 20:12:44,821] WARN This transcoder (JsonBinaryTranscoder) does not support mutation tokens - this method is a stub and needs to be implemented on custom transcoders. (com.couchbase.client.java.transcoder.AbstractTranscoder:150)
[2017-11-07 20:12:44,823] ERROR Task test-couchbase-sink-1 threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:455)
com.couchbase.client.java.error.CannotRetryException: maximum number of attempts reached after 5 retries
    at com.couchbase.client.java.util.retry.RetryWithDelayHandler.call(RetryWithDelayHandler.java:101)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.util.retry.RetryWithDelayHandler.call(RetryWithDelayHandler.java:42)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:69)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorZip$Zip.tick(OperatorZip.java:252)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorZip$Zip$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorZip.java:323)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:77)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo$3$1.onNext(OnSubscribeRedo.java:302)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo$3$1.onNext(OnSubscribeRedo.java:284)
    at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.accept(NotificationLite.java:135)
    at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager$SubjectObserver.emitNext(SubjectSubscriptionManager.java:253)
    at rx.subjects.BehaviorSubject.onNext(BehaviorSubject.java:160)
    at rx.observers.SerializedObserver.onNext(SerializedObserver.java:91)
    at rx.subjects.SerializedSubject.onNext(SerializedSubject.java:67)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo$2$1.onError(OnSubscribeRedo.java:237)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.reportError(OperatorMerge.java:266)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.checkTerminate(OperatorMerge.java:818)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:579)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:568)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onError(OperatorMerge.java:852)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeMap.java:88)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:73)
    at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onNext(Subscribers.java:235)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:101)
    at rx.internal.producers.SingleProducer.request(SingleProducer.java:65)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
    at rx.subjects.AsyncSubject.onCompleted(AsyncSubject.java:103)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.completeResponse(AbstractGenericHandler.java:390)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.access$000(AbstractGenericHandler.java:72)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler$1.call(AbstractGenericHandler.java:408)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.couchbase.connect.kafka.util.JsonBinaryTranscoder.newDocument(JsonBinaryTranscoder.java:40)
    at com.couchbase.connect.kafka.util.JsonBinaryTranscoder.newDocument(JsonBinaryTranscoder.java:30)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.transcoder.AbstractTranscoder.newDocument(AbstractTranscoder.java:133)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseAsyncBucket$16.call(CouchbaseAsyncBucket.java:568)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseAsyncBucket$16.call(CouchbaseAsyncBucket.java:560)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:69)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable$OnNextValue: OnError while emitting onNext value: com.couchbase.client.core.message.kv.UpsertResponse.class
    at rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable.addValueAsLastCause(OnErrorThrowable.java:118)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:73)
    ... 19 more
[2017-11-07 20:12:44,830] ERROR Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:456)
[2017-11-07 20:12:44,830] ERROR Task test-couchbase-sink-1 threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:148)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:457)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:251)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:180)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:148)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:190)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2017-11-07 20:12:44,831] **ERROR Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted** (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:149)
[2017-11-07 20:12:44,836] INFO Closed bucket test (com.couchbase.client.core.config.ConfigurationProvider:115)
[2017-11-07 20:12:44,836] INFO Disconnected from Node 10.103.2.76/localhost (com.couchbase.client.core.node.Node:115)
```

**[2017-11-07 20:12:44,839] INFO [null][KeyValueEndpoint]: Got notified from Channel as inactive, attempting reconnect. (com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.Endpoint:115)**

**Thank you for Reading**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for raising this issue. This is a regression in version 3.2.0 of the connector. It is being tracked as [KAFKAC-83](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/KAFKAC-83).

The fix is included in version 3.2.1, <s>scheduled for release on November 21, 2017</s> released on November 8, 2017.

In the meantime you may wish to temporarily downgrade to [version 3.1.3](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.0/connectors/kafka-3.1/release-notes.html), or build the connector from the [latest source code](https://github.com/couchbase/kafka-connect-couchbase).

PSA: The Couchbase forums have a dedicated section for [discussion related to the Kafka connector](https://forums.couchbase.com/c/Kafka-Connector).

Comment: Thanks a lot dnault !

Comment: @user6782126 You're welcome! We released version 3.2.1 today ahead of schedule, specifically to resolve this issue.

Comment: Oh.. so great ! Thank you very much